# App build error with Expo and AWS-Amplify

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, aws-amplify

I am trying to build my react-native app with Expo, the project is working correctly on the local host, however when trying to build my Expo application, I came across the following error message:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ./src/aws-exports from /home/expo/workingdir/build/App.js: 

None of these files exist:

  * src/aws-exports(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs)

  * src/aws-exports/index(.native|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs)

  21 | import { Amplify } from '@aws-amplify/core';

  22 | import { Storage } from '@aws-amplify/storage';

> 23 | import awsconfig from './src/aws-exports';

     |                        ^
.
.
.
```

Here are the actions I took to try to resolve the problem:

- I deleted and reinstalled `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, in the
  hope that the error was due to some corruption in the modules.
- I used the `expo start -c` command to clear Expo's cache.
- I reviewed my module configuration and made sure that the aws-exports file was in the right place and with the right name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution that worked for me was to create a new folder to put the settings from the `aws-exports.js` file.

For example, I created an `AWSexports` file inside the `components` folder.

And I imported `import awsconfig from './components/AWSexports'`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `aws-exports.js` from your `.gitignore`.